# Changing variable of integration

Tags: integration

So, I am a bit confused as to the subtle difference between something like $\int_0^5xdx$ and $\int_0^5x\frac {dx}{dt}dt$. Would these be computed differently? My thinking is that a small change in x per change in t multiplied by that change in t gives us the total change in x. In other words, is it correct to say $\frac {dx}{dt}dt = dx$? Would these two integrals have the same exact values? If not, why, and how would I know the how to correctly compute the two different integrals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{5}x\dfrac{dx}{dt}dt=\int_{x(0)}^{x(5)}xdx\ne\int_{0}^{5}xdx
\end{align*}
in general, here $x'>0$ is assumed, and the left-sided is dealing with function $x=x(t)$ where the right-sided is dealing with function $x\rightarrow x$.

Comment: So, if it were an indefinite integral without limits of integration, would the two be the same then? Would they both be equal to (x^2)/2 + c?

Comment: I don't think so. The indefinite of the left-sided should be $(1/2)(x(t))^{2}$ where the right-sided should be $(1/2)x^{2}$, they are different, whereas the former is a function of $t$ and the later is a function of $x$, although they look as if they have the same form.